# how do I write these numbers to a list in that because I tried using a for loop but it doesn't work and write it to a a list called list_of_numbers

Tags: python

```py
list_of_numbers = []

numbers = "[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, -1.0, -10.0, 10.0]"
```

Comment: What do you mean by write to a list?

Comment: What is your input, what is your desired output, and what have you tried already (i.e. show what you tried with the for loop)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to convert the string representation of the list to a proper list, do this:

```
import ast
numbers = "[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, -1.0, -10.0, 10.0]"
list_of_numbers=list(ast.literal_eval(numbers))
print (list_of_numbers)
```